# Has anyone found a "pattern" in prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fractals, open-problem

Yesterday I was having some fun trying to look for some patterns in primes; and I think I found something interesting.

The idea is to start with an array of primes `{p1, p2, p3, ... }`, print it, then set the value at index `i = abs( [i] - [i-1] )` or put more formally, set the value at `i` equal to the "prime gap"; then repeat this, but use the prime gaps and find their gaps. And so on.

[image: Sample output] screenshot.

You can see at the top row we start with the primes, then their gaps, then their gaps, and so on. It starts to produce that triangle pattern [image: better seen here]

---

Here is the code to produce the pattern I've found. If you run the code you can see the pattern, it's actually pretty fascinating!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PrimeSandbox 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JTextArea screen = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 8);
    screen.setFont(font);
    screen.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(screen); 
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane);
     //frame.pack();
     frame.setLocation(0, 0);
     frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    int arrsize = 150;
    int[] parrOrig = {  2,      3,      5,      7,     11,     13,     17,     19,     23,     29, 
             31,     37,     41,     43,     47,     53,     59,     61,     67,     71, 
             73,     79,     83,     89,     97,    101,    103,    107,    109,    113, 
            127,    131,    137,    139,    149,    151,    157,    163,    167,    173, 
            179,    181,    191,    193,    197,    199,    211,    223,    227,    229, 
            233,    239,    241,    251,    257,    263,    269,    271,    277,    281, 
            283,    293,    307,    311,    313,    317,    331,    337,    347,    349, 
            353,    359,    367,    373,    379,    383,    389,    397,    401,    409, 
            419,    421,    431,    433,    439,    443,    449,    457,    461,    463, 
            467,    479,    487,    491,    499,    503,    509,    521,    523,    541, 
            547,    557,    563,    569,    571,    577,    587,    593,    599,    601, 
            607,    613,    617,    619,    631,    641,    643,    647,    653,    659, 
            661,    673,    677,    683,    691,    701,    709,    719,    727,    733, 
            739,    743,    751,    757,    761,    769,    773,    787,    797,    809, 
            811,    821,    823,    827,    829,    839,    853,    857,    859,    863, 
            877,    881,    883,    887,    907,    911,    919,    929,    937,    941, 
            947,    953,    967,    971,    977,    983,    991,    997,   1009,   1013 };
    int [] parr = Arrays.copyOf(parrOrig, arrsize);
    int lines = 0;
    while(lines < 1000)
    {
        int[] oldarr = Arrays.copyOf(parr,arrsize);

        for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
            screen.append(" " + oldarr[i]);
        screen.append("\n");
        screen.setCaretPosition(screen.getText().length());

        for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                parr[i] = 0;
            else
                parr[i] = Math.abs(oldarr[i] - oldarr[i-1]);
        }
        lines++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: it looks like the Sierpiński triangle

Comment: Sierpinski triangles?

Comment: The question in the title, "has anyone found a pattern in prime numbers," the answer depends on what you call a pattern. Indeed, there is a very simple pattern --- all of them are prime. The other question you ask, whether anyone has done the calculations you have done, I'm sure the answer is yes. I think the relevant search term is Andrica's conjecture. No, wait, I just checked it, that's the wrong one. I'll come back if I find the right one. Ah, Gilbreath's conjecture, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture

Comment: I guess it is close. Though Gilbreaths conjecture just says that the first column is always ones; not sure if it is different, but look at those triangles so pretty!.. Sierpinski, I think his triangles are made from a curve, mine are from primes? Does that make them different?

Comment: @BumSkeeter: They aren't *quite* Sierpinski triangles, since they (seem to) iterate "outward", rather than "inward".

Comment: @CameronBuie: it _is_ the Sierpinski triangle, at least the cellular automata interpretation of it. See item 9 [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Sierpinski.shtml).

Comment: What I said was, yes, someone has done the calculations you have done --- and carried them a lot farther than you did. Have you looked at the links at Wikipedia, to see whether Odlyzko et al made any comments on patterns? Do that before you decide what you have done is different.

Comment: @Willie: Interesting! I'd only ever seen the trema-removal construction.

Comment: What you're doing is called "recursive forward differencing". If some generation of the forward differnces turn out to be nice and simple, then you can often work backwards and get a reasonably simple function that generates the original values. For example, if the n-th generation of forward differences are all zero, you can work backwards to get a polynomial.

Comment: @Gerry trying to get his paper at the bottom of the wiki page on "Gilbreath". Its called "Iterated absolute values of differences of consecutive primes". Its a .ps file, gotta figure out how to use that.

Comment: .ps is postscript. If you're on a Mac, Preview should open it for you. If you're on Windows, I'm sure there's something that will open it, but I don't know what.

Comment: Found something. The paper wasn't much. This explains it a little better. http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/GilbreathsConjecture.html

Odlyzko's paper talks about Gilbreath's conjecture as far as I can tell. But I cant read maths that well.

Comment: Ghostscript (and GhostGum) are the usual tools for reading .ps files on non-Mac machines.

Comment: Yeah I got it. There is nothing in the paper from Odlyzko about the pattern. He only speak of the first column. Nothing of the pattern I see. He does describe the method to get to it, but I dont think he looked to the other columns and saw this.

Comment: @BumSkeeter: your evolution is **not** the same as the one in Gilbreaths Conjecture. You are taking differences with the element on the *left*, while the Gilbreaths Conjecture deal with differences with element on the *right*. This makes a **huge** difference. His first column is in fact your _diagonal_.

Comment: Google prime number solved fractal. Prime numbers can be solved :) they follow a fractal pattern. Dam you scary nature!

Comment: Just happened to stumble upon a very related website/post today. 
http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_274.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that we can write your iteration scheme as, for $i \geq 0$
$$\begin{align}
x(0,i) & = \text{given sequence of nonnegative integers}\\
x(n+1,i) & = \begin{cases} 0 & i = 0 \\
\left|x(n, i) - x(n,i-1)\right| & i > 0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

The first implication of this definition is that

> **Property 1** the value of $x(n,i)$ is determined completely by the values $x(0,0), x(0,1), \ldots, x(0,i)$.

Let us define $M(n,i) = \max_{0 \leq j \leq i} x(n,j)$.

> **Lemma 2** For any initial distribution of nonnegative integers, $M(n,i)$ is nondecreasing in $i$ and nonincreasing in $n$.

*Proof*: nondecrease in $i$ is clear from the definition of $M$. Nonincrease in $n$ follows from the recursive relation and the fact that all numbers involved are non-positive, so $|x(n,i) - x(n,i-1)| \leq \max( x(n,i), x(n,i-1)) \leq M(n,i)$. q.e.d.

> **Lemma 3** For any initial distribution of nonnegative integers, if there exists a $i_0 \geq 0$ and $n_0 \geq 0$ such that $M(n_0,i_0) = 0$, then the first $i_0 + 1$ numbers in the data are all the same.

*Proof*: By the recursion rule we easily see that if $n_0 > 1$, then $M(n_0, i_0) = 0 \iff M(n_0 - 1, i_0) = 0$. (We start from $x(n_0 - 1, 0) = 0$ and solve increasing in $i$.) If $M(1,i_0) = 0$ then necessarily the first $i_0 + 1$ numbers in the data are all equal. q.e.d.

> **Corollary 4** If for some $i_0,n_0 > 0$ we have that $M(n_0,i_0) \neq 0$, then for any $n \geq n_0$ we also have $M(n, i_0) \neq 0$.

The corollary can be used to show

> **Proposition 5** Let $n_0 > 0$ and $i_0 > 0$ be fixed. Suppose $M(n_0, i_0) \neq 0$. Then $x(n,i_0+1)$ will eventually, as $n$ increases, decay to be at most $M(n_0,i_0)$.

*Proof (sketch):* We argue by contradiction. Suppose always $x(n,i_0+1) = M(n,i_0+1) > M(n_0,i_0) > 0$. Since $M(n,i_0+1)$ is nonincreasing in $n$, we have that $x(n,i_0+1)$ converges to some $x_0 > M(n_0, i_0)$ in finite time. Suppose $x(n,i_0+1) = x_0$ for all $N \leq n \leq N + 2i_0$ as guaranteed by the convergence. This requires that $x(n,i_0) = 0$ for all $N \leq n \leq N + 2i_0 - 1$, and iterating by induction we see that this implies for all $N \leq n \leq N + i_0 - 2$ and all $0 \leq i \leq i_0$ that $x(n,i) = 0$, thus showing $M(n,i_0) = 0$, which gives a contradiction. q.e.d.

> **Corollary 6** for any initial data such that $|x(0,0) - x(0,1)| = 1$ (The list of prime numbers, for example), we have that for any $i_0 > 0$ we can find some $n_0 > 0$ such that for all $n > n_0$, $M(n,i_0) = 1$.

*Proof:* We know that $M(1,1) = 1$. The previous proposition implies that for sufficiently large $n$, $x(n,2) \leq 1$, hence $M(n,2) = 1$. By induction this holds true for all $i_0$.

---

Notice that Property 1 implies that once we have an initial segment that looks like a line from the Sierpinski gasket, the rectangular region below it will be exactly the Sierpinski gasket type evolution.

Now, also note that your system is taking differences with the element "to the left". If you take differences with the element "to the right" you end up in the situation in [Gilbreath's Conjecture](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/GilbreathsConjecture.html). The previous paragraph in fact shows:

> Gilbreath's Conjecture is equivalent to the statement that "the Sierpinski gasket pattern below the diagonal that you observed continues indefinitely."

Comment: This says what I found converges to a Sierpinski gasket? (I really wish I could read it, I mean I can somewhat follow it, but I cant pull the reasoning out of it, and I do not know enough about Sierpinski to correlate) Give me a few days and I'll get it :) And thank you Willie for the time you've spent for me! Shoot me a PM with your email and I will send you the visualizer I am trying to make for the pattern!

Comment: No, it doesn't say that (unfortunately). What I showed is that the statement "what you found actually converges to a Sierpinski gasket" is **equivalent** to Gilbreath's conjecture; if you prove one, you prove the other. What we know is that for the first $10^13$ columns in your diagram, as you scroll down you will converge to Sierpinski gasket (since Odlyzko checked that far). For larger numbers I don't know.

Comment: Roughly speaking, what I showed is that if you fix your eyes on a column and wait sufficiently long, the numbers in the column will eventually decrease to just 0s and 1s. Whether they actually form the Sierpinski pattern requires much more detailed analysis.

Comment: You put more formally, that the absolute value of the difference of two numbers can never be negative? (Weird weird way to look at it; doesn't encompass it all either; faster conclusion I can draw though)

Comment: Also if your'e interested thread about the visualizer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25436/help-me-speed-up-this-java-code-deals-with-huge-list-of-ints

Comment: @BumSkeeter: I am sorry but I do not understand what you intend to say with [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371434/has-anyone-found-a-pattern-in-prime-numbers/371537?noredirect=1#comment796177_371537), and so cannot answer you.

Comment: " will eventually decrease to just 0s and 1s" this is because we are taking the difference and absolute value, so our numbers (gaps) always get smaller and never get smaller than 0. Once we hit 1's and 0's we cannot go smaller and since we are subtracting we cannot get anything larger because of the absolute value of the subtraction. So the pattern will tend to 1's and 0's after some time. [thats what I was trying to say if i makes sense]

Comment: The main question is: "why must it eventually decrease to 1" or smaller? If you start with the sequence $0,0,0,15, \ldots$, the fourth column will remain 15 forever (never actually get smaller). Most of the work I put into the above answer is to show that this situation cannot happen from many initial data sets.

Comment: Ok, so what you showed is that it is very I guess "rare" to get a pattern as such? You don't just get them by randomly choosing increasing positive integers?

Comment: Corollary 6 states that you will get eventual decrease down to 0s and 1s if you start with a list of numbers, the difference of the first two being precisely 1. (You can modify this so that it also holds for any sequence of numbers starting like $x,x,x,x,x,x\pm 1, \ldots$, where the first "different" number is one more or less than the previous ones. The Guy's Conjecture (see the Gilbreath link) is that you get exactly the Sierpinski like structure if, in addition to the above, all numbers in the list except for $x$ has the same parity (all even or all odd, necessarily $x$ has the opposite...

Comment: parity), and that the list of numbers is increasing sufficiently slowly, and that the density of the numbers decreases sufficiently regularly. If you read through and understand my answer you will also understand why there needs to be rate constraint in Guy's conjecture.

Comment: Because 2 is even, and the rest are prime (so 2 cant divide them) and odd. So its not that the primes are special its just that they show that trait? And any list with that trait will create the triangle I see?

Comment: And also the slow growth condition. I would prefer if you ask your questions *after* you read everything I wrote, so I do not have to repeat myself so often.

Answer (score 2):

Given any sequence starting with $2$ and then containing only even numbers will produce Sierpinski-like patterns emerging and growing from the left.

If the triangle meets a $0$ or $2$ at its right end, it continues to grow. Otherwise, it starts afresh while decreasing the number at the right end it will meet the next time, until it has decayed enough to allow the triangle to grow further to the right.

Comment: Consider initial data `0222002`, Next row is `0200202`, then `0220222`, then `0202200`, then `0222020`, then `0200222`, then `0220200`, then `0202220`, then `0222002` which is what we started with. This never actually converges to the Sierpinski pattern.